# codeigniter- search and display data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display data from database to the view but I am unable to do so. 
the problem I am having is that how do I display the data in a table tag while connecting it with the controller.

View:

```
<form action="#" class="login-wrapper" method="get">
    <div class="span12" align="center">
     <input class="input span12 password" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search by name">
    <div class="actions">
     <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="sub" value="search now">
    </div>
    </div >
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function select ($search){

    $this->load->model('Login_model');

    if(isset($_GET ['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {

        $search= $_GET[ 'search'];
        $this->load->model('Login_model');

        if($this->Login_model->selectorganizer($search))
        {
           $this->load->view('organizer');

        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin/show');
        }
    }  
}
```

Model:

```
public function selectorganizer ($search) {
    $condition = "search = '" . $search . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('organizer');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your field name is `name="data[search]"`

So you get in by using `$_GET['data']['search']`

```
<?php print_r($_GET['data']['search']);?>
```

OR

You have to change your field name according to your code `name="search"`

```
<input class="input span12 password" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search by name">
```

Controller

You have to call your view and pass your query result

```
<?php
public function select ($search){

    $this->load->model('Login_model');

    if(isset($_GET ['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {

        $search= $_GET[ 'search'];
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
        $result=$this->Login_model->selectorganizer($search)''

        if($result)
        {
            $data['result']=$result;
             $this->load->view('YOUR_VIEW', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin/show');
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: have you got your search data to controller and have you able to call your model file

Comment: Thats what I am not able to do, I call the view in controller and i want to display the data in a table tag.

Comment: Quick question, I should be able to make a table and call all the data there? now that I can send data back to view, right?

Comment: yes you can make your table now your data in your view you can represent your data in nay way